# Python - How to check if next few elements in list meet some statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a huge list of values, and I want to search for pattern: if listItem == some value and next 10 items in list meet some statement, then do something. How to do this to avoid long multiple if condition code like that?

```
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    if list[i] == someValue and list[i+1] !=someValue and list[i+2] !=someValue and [...] and list[i+10] !=someValue: 
        doSomething()
```

Comment: Despite having a `huge list` you should first limit your iteration with: `range(len(mylist) - 10)`

Comment: So `someValue` is the same for all 11 conditions?

Comment: @quamrana That's not needed, `a = [1, 2, 3]; a[3:13]` will not raise an error, it will just give as many elements as it can.in this case 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == someValue and all(x != someValue for x in lst[i+1:i+11]): 
        doSomething()
```

I changed the variable name from `list` to `lst` because you shopuld not overwrite the `list` builtin type and I also removed the `0` in the `range` fucntion as it is not needed.

The `all` fucntion checks that every element in the iterable passed as argument evaluates to `True`, and our iterable is a sequence of bools with the next 10 elements checked against `someValue`.

Another option would be using `enumerate(...)` to avoid having to get the value again from the list instead of `range(len(...))`:

```py
for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    if value == someValue and all(x != someValue for x in lst[i+1:i+11]): 
        doSomething()
```

And we could make it into a generator:

```py
for i in (i for i, value in enumerate(lst) if value == someValue and all(x != someValue for x in lst[i+1:i+11])):
    doSomething()
```

@HeapOverflow suggested another way to check for that condition which is more readable (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63883473/5612096) for further detail and drop a like) that conbined with the generator syntax would be:

```py
for i in (i for i, value in enumerate(lst) if value == someValue not in lst[i+1:i+11]):
    doSomething()
```

Comment: @HeapOverflow Like building a set of the next ten numbers, checking if we have only one element and then checking that element against the value? (Comment is pointless now, since the comment I'm referring to was deleted)

Comment: Oh, I see. Good idea.

Comment: @HeapOverflow The generator version combined with your check definetely looks the best to me, do you mind if I also add that with proper credit?

Comment: Go ahead if you like that :-)

Comment: Btw I'm also thinking of writing a more efficient solution, only finding the *matching* indices and instead of checking that the next ten values differ, just check whether the next matching index is far enough away. I just don't really want to go that far since I'm still not convinced of the question and the OP is ignoring my clarification question comment.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Something like filtering a pandas `DataFrame`, compuitng the deltas of the index and filtering by less than 10? Guess that that approach would be more performant for very big arrays.

Comment: Sounds right, yes (I'm not familiar with pandas yet).

Answer (score 1):

Using membership test and [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```py
for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    if value == someValue not in lst[i+1:i+11]:
        doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you are searching for arbitrary values?

```py
target = [someValue1, someValue2, ... someValue11]
for i in range (len(lst) - 10):
    if lst[i:i+11] == target: 
        doSomething()
```

Comment: You missed the negative comparissons, and limiting the range is not needed.

Comment: What are `negative comparissons`?

Comment: He only has a `==` for the first element but then he has `!=` for the following 10 items.

Comment: Ok, missed that! Is that what `next 10 items in list meet some statement` meant?

Comment: That's what I understood.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    if list[i] == someValue and all(x != someValue for x in list[i+1:i+10]): 
        doSomething()
```

Comment: Should be `all(x != someValue for x in ist[i+1:i+10])`